# why other object change is getting reflected to object it has copied from

Tags: javascript

In below code I copied item to dummyItem and then changed the description property of dummyItem then why Item's description property is also getting changed. customFilter function gets called for no of items one after another.

```
Item structure

item = {brand: "test_brand", categorygroup: "Food & Drink", categoryid: 131, categorytext: "Breweries", description:"<b><i>the new description</i><b>", listprice: 123, noofrewards: 14, supplieditems: 1, title: "test_dev"}

customFilter : function(item, args) {
                    if (args.searchString != "" && item.productid.toFixed(2).indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1 
                                                && item.shortid.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1 
                                                && item.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1
                                                && item.brand.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1 
                                                && item.description.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1 
                                                && item.categorytext.toLowerCase(2).indexOf(args.searchString) == -1 
                                                && item.companyid.toFixed(2).indexOf(args.searchString) == -1 
                                                && item.listprice.toFixed(2).indexOf(args.searchString) == -1 
                                                && item.currency.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.searchString.toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                        return false;
                    }
                    var dummyItem = item;
                    dummyItem.description = $('<div></div>').html(item.description).text();
                    $self.filteredData.push(dummyItem);
                    return true;
                },
```

Comment: you didn't copy the object, you just made a new shortcut to it.

Comment: so how can I make copy then

Comment: copy=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj)); (for data props only) if you want to clone object with inherted stuff and methods, it's complicated...

Comment: Thanks. Also found this

    var copiedObject = jQuery.extend({},originalObject);

Comment: Thanks all for reply. I found the answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Answer (score 0):

You are referring to the same object:

```
var dummyItem = item;
```

```js
var src = {
  'a': 45
};
console.log('src, ', src);
var trg = src; // trg is pointing to src
console.log('trg, ', trg);
var cpy = {
  'a': 45
};
console.log('cpy, ', cpy);
console.log('src === trg, ', src === trg); //true
console.log('src === cpy, ', src === cpy); //false
```

```html
Open console ...
```